# Как достать из строки LocalTime?

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Наш препод решил нас озадачить и вот сейчас у нас есть вот такой массив строк `String[] attributes = line.split(";");` в нем мы разделяем вот такую строку `1508877719;KRP;All;Text;` есстественно что потом у нас будут вот такие переменные у этого массива:

```
attributes[0] = "1508877719"; 
attributes[1] = "KRP";
attributes[2] = "All";
attributes[3] = "Text";
```

И потом у нас есть Лист в который надо засовывать всё это, все-бы ничего только вот с первым проблема есть потому вот это `attributes[0] = "1508877719";` мы должны засунуть в `LocalTime`, и перевести эту строку в `LocalTime` я не могу, и это не так просто. Буду благодарен если кто-то даст совет или объяснит как это сделать.
Пробывал всякие варианты:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH'mmsss'nnn");
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(attributes[0],format);
```

и просто parse тоже пробывал

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(attributes[0]);
```

после всего этого пишет исключение:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1508877719' could not be parsed at index 2
```

и пишет что проблема именно на той строке, в которой я пытаюсь перевести String в LocalTime.

Comment: Для начала объясните, что это за число и как из него  получить время? Без кода. Словами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так у вас строка `"1508877719"`, а форматер используете `"HH'mmsss'nnn"`.

Если `"1508877719"` - это секунды, то вот так делайте:

```
long ms = Long.valueOf(attributes[0]) * 1000; // будут миллисекунды
LocalTime  time = Instant.ofEpochMilli(ms).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Так, число `1508877719` похоже на UnixTime `24 Oct 2017 20:41:59 GMT`. Тогда все просто: переводим строку в число, а число уже во время методом `Instant.ofEpochMilli(long)` с указанием нужной временной зоны

```
String str = "1508877719";
int unixTime = Integer.parseInt(str);
LocalDateTime date =
  LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
    Instant.ofEpochSecond(unixTime), 
    ZoneId.systemDefault()
  );
System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
```

Comment: `ofEpochMilli` требует мс, а `1508877719` - это, очевидно, секунды.

Comment: @Suvitruf Вы правы. Исправил ответ